# Reading XML (NIST .n42 file) and data extraction

Tags: python, xml, elementtree, minidom

I have a xml file that I need to extract data from 'channelData' in the below xml.

```
from xml.dom import minidom
xmldoc = minidom.parse('Annex_B_n42.xml')
itemlist = xmldoc.getElementsByTagName('ChannelData')
print(len(itemlist))
print(itemlist[0].attributes['compressionCode'].value)
for s in itemlist:
    print(s.attributes['compressionCode'].value)
```

Which doesn't return the data, just the value 'None'.

I also tried another approach from an another example:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('Annex_B_n42.xml').getroot()
#value=[]
for type_tag in root.findall('Spectrum'):
    value = type_tag.get('id')
    print(value)

print("data from file " +str(value))
```

This did not work at all and `value` is not being populated.  I really don't understand how to parse xml.

Here is the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-model href="http://physics.nist.gov/N42/2011/N42/schematron/n42.sch" type="application/xml" schematypens="http://purl.oclc.org/dsdl/schematron"?>
<RadInstrumentData xmlns="http://physics.nist.gov/N42/2011/N42" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://physics.nist.gov/N42/2011/N42 file:///d:/Data%20Files/ANSI%20N42%2042/V2/Schema/n42.xsd" n42DocUUID="d72b7fa7-4a20-43d4-b1b2-7e3b8c6620c1">

  <RadInstrumentInformation id="RadInstrumentInformation-1">
    <RadInstrumentManufacturerName>RIIDs R Us</RadInstrumentManufacturerName>
    <RadInstrumentModelName>iRIID</RadInstrumentModelName>
    <RadInstrumentClassCode>Radionuclide Identifier</RadInstrumentClassCode>
    <RadInstrumentVersion>
      <RadInstrumentComponentName>Software</RadInstrumentComponentName>
      <RadInstrumentComponentVersion>1.1</RadInstrumentComponentVersion>
    </RadInstrumentVersion>
  </RadInstrumentInformation>

  <RadDetectorInformation id="RadDetectorInformation-1">
      <RadDetectorCategoryCode>Gamma</RadDetectorCategoryCode>
      <RadDetectorKindCode>NaI</RadDetectorKindCode>
  </RadDetectorInformation>

  <EnergyCalibration id="EnergyCalibration-1">
    <CoefficientValues>-21.8 12.1 6.55e-03</CoefficientValues>
  </EnergyCalibration> 

  <RadMeasurement id="RadMeasurement-1">
    <MeasurementClassCode>Foreground</MeasurementClassCode>
    <StartDateTime>2003-11-22T23:45:19-07:00</StartDateTime>
    <RealTimeDuration>PT60S</RealTimeDuration>
    <Spectrum id="RadMeasurement-1Spectrum-1" radDetectorInformationReference="RadDetectorInformation-1" energyCalibrationReference="EnergyCalibration-1"> 
      <LiveTimeDuration>PT59.61S</LiveTimeDuration>
      <ChannelData compressionCode="None">
        0 0 0 22 421 847 1295 1982 2127 2222 2302 2276
        2234 1921 1939 1715 1586 1469 1296 1178 1127 1047 928 760
        679 641 542 529 443 423 397 393 322 272 294 227
        216 224 208 191 189 163 167 173 150 137 136 129
        150 142 160 159 140 103 90 82 83 85 67 76
        73 84 63 74 70 69 76 61 49 61 63 65
        58 62 48 75 56 61 46 56 43 37 55 47
        50 40 38 54 43 41 45 51 32 35 29 33
        40 44 33 35 20 26 27 17 19 20 16 19
        18 19 18 20 17 45 55 70 62 59 32 30
        21 23 10 9 5 13 11 11 6 7 7 9
        11 4 8 8 14 14 11 9 13 5 5 6
        10 9 3 4 3 7 5 5 4 5 3 6
        5 0 5 6 3 1 4 4 3 10 11 4
        1 4 2 11 9 6 3 5 5 1 4 2
        6 6 2 3 0 2 2 2 2 0 1 3
        1 1 2 3 2 4 5 2 6 4 1 0
        3 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 0 2 0 1
        0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
        0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 0
        0 0 1 3 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
        0 0 0 0 
      </ChannelData> 
    </Spectrum>
  </RadMeasurement> 
</RadInstrumentData>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use BeautifulSoup to get the channeldata tag value like following

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('Annex_B_n42.xml') as f:
    xml = f.read()
bs_obj = BeautifulSoup(xml)
print(bs_obj.find_all("channeldata")[0].text)
```

That will print you

```
'         0 0 0 22 421 847 1295 1982 2127 2222 2302 2276         2234 1921 1939 1715 1586 1469 1296 1178 1127 1047 928 760         679 641 542 529 443 423 397 393 322 272 294 227         216 224 208 191 189 163 167 173 150 137 136 129         150 142 160 159 140 103 90 82 83 85 67 76         73 84 63 74 70 69 76 61 49 61 63 65         58 62 48 75 56 61 46 56 43 37 55 47         50 40 38 54 43 41 45 51 32 35 29 33         40 44 33 35 20 26 27 17 19 20 16 19
  18 19 18 20 17 45 55 70 62 59 32 30         21 23 10 9 5 13 11 11 6 7 7 9         11 4 8 8 14 14 11 9 13 5 5 6         10 9 3 4 3 7 5 5 4 5 3 6         5 0 5 6 3 1 4 4 3 10 11 4         1 4 2 11 9 6 3 5 5 1 4 2         6 6 2 3 0 2 2 2 2 0 1 3         1 1 2 3 2 4 5 2 6 4 1 0         3 1 2 1 1 0 1 0 0 2 0 1         0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2         0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0 2 1 0 0         0 0 1 3 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0         0 0 0 0       '
```

Comment: Thank you.  Very neat and clean.  I'll need to read more about BeautifulSoup and maybe use this in the future.

Comment: How can I use your example to get 'StartDateTime'.  I get an error 'IndexError: list index out of range'

Comment: .find_all("StartDateTime".lower()) use lower case when you searching with this method

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.parse('Annex_B_n42.xml').getroot()
elems = root.findall(".//*[@compressionCode='None']")
print(elems[0].text)
```

Comment: Can you explain how this works?  What does the .//* etc etc do.  I don't see how you are getting to 'ChannelData'?

Comment: refer this [xpath syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#supported-xpath-syntax)